# How to join and match data from two XML files using XQuery?

Tags: filtering, xquery, match

I need to combine data from two XML files using XQuery and to create an HTML table with the data.

The first file contains elements with an attribute, which identifies the elements:

```
<element id="x"/>
<element id="x2"/>
```

The second file contains another identifier, and an element that cross-references the element in the first file:

```
<2nd-element id="y" xref="x"/>
<2nd-element id="y2" xref="x2"/>
```

How do I filter the data so that I am left with the following result?

```
  <table>
   <tbody>
   <tr><td>x</td><td>y</td></tr>
   <tr><td>x2</td><td>y2</td></tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

Currently, I am able to populate the second column with all **xref** attributes from the second file, but how do I filter out the unwanted data?

How do I include the expression to filter the data in the expression is used to populate the table columns?

```
{data(2nd-element/@xref)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You walk the ids of the first file, match the id of the second file, and create one table row for each pair:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
  {
    for $id1 in $first-file//element/@id
    let $id2 := $second-file//element-2nd[@xref = $id1]/@id
    return <tr><td>{data($id1)}</td><td>{data($id2)}</td></tr>
  }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you Gunther: I had misplaced `[@xref = $id1]` to the attribute @id.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what data is unwanted. You just have to insert the values of the two attributes `xref` and `id` of the `2nd-element`s. The `element`s are not necessary to produce the desired output using just the 2nd snippet.

Comment: The first file apparently indicates those that are wanted in the result.